# Impossible to unwrap COM instance from custom domain

Tags: c#, .net, com, appdomain

I'm trying to make a call inside a COM components from a custom domain.
The problem is when I try to unwrap my ObjectHandle an Serialization exception is throw.

But if I use the current AppDomain to create the instance, it's working....

The exception message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in ConsoleApp1.exe
Additional information: Type 'MyAddin.Main' in assembly 'MyAddin, Version=2019.0.1.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

And my code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string addinPath = "C:\\sources\\MyAddin\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\MyAddin.dll";
            string addinFolder = "C:\\sources\\MyAddin\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\";
            string addinConfigPath = "C:\\sources\\MyAddin\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\MyAddin.dll.config";

            System.AppDomainSetup setup = new System.AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ApplicationBase = addinFolder;
            setup.ConfigurationFile = addinConfigPath;
            setup.ApplicationName = "MyAddin.dll";

            string strClsid = "{2616ad89-f4d1-4dc7-9d9d-a5de101b9085}"; // CLSID of my COM addin

            System.AppDomain customDomain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(strClsid,  null,  setup);
            // The type of domain is System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}

            // The type of custom domain is 
            System.Type addinComType = System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.Guid.Parse(strClsid));

            System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle addinInstanceObjectHandle = customDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(addinPath, addinComType.FullName); 
            System.Object addinInstance = addinInstanceObjectHandle.Unwrap(); //Throw the Serialization exception when create COM instance from customDomain
            // But working if I did System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom

            System.Reflection.MethodBase myMethod = addinInstance.GetType().GetMethod("connectToEwAPI");
            System.Object[] parameters = { null };
            myMethod.Invoke(addinInstance, parameters);

        }
    }
}
```

So I do something stupid ?
Do you know what I'm missing ?

Thanks in advance for your help

---

### Edit

I have tried with more basic Assembly.
So I have an C# assembly with just this code

```
namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {

        }
        public string MyMethod() => "OK";
    }
}
```

And my exe code is just

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string basePath = @"C:\source\MyAddin\ConsoleApp1\ClassLibrary2\bin\Debug";
    string dllName = @"ClassLibrary2";
    string typeName = "ClassLibrary2.Class1";
    string dllFullpath = $"{basePath}\\{dllName}.dll";

    try
    {
        ObjectHandle objectHandle = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(dllFullpath, typeName);
        Object addinObject = objectHandle.Unwrap();
        var myAddinMethod = addinObject.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
        string result = myAddinMethod.Invoke(addinObject, null) as string; // Working


        AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup()
        {
            ApplicationBase = basePath,
            ApplicationName = dllName,
            ConfigurationFile = dllName + ".dll.config",
            PrivateBinPath = basePath
        };

        AppDomain customDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", null, setup);
        ObjectHandle objectHandleFromCustomDomain = customDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(dllFullpath, typeName);
        Object addinObjectFromCustomDomain = objectHandleFromCustomDomain.Unwrap();  // Exception thrown
        var myAddinMethodFromCustomDomain = addinObjectFromCustomDomain.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
        string resultFromCustomDomain = myAddinMethodFromCustomDomain.Invoke(myAddinMethodFromCustomDomain, null) as string;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        var t = e.Message; // Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' by objectHandleFromCustomDomain.Unwrap()
    }
}
```

So as you can see, it's working with the default domain but not with the custom one....

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Using a [ComVisible] .NET class or interface from managed code is a pretty bad idea.  The IDE and the type library importer try very hard to stop you from doing this.  But they can be defeated, no protection when you use late binding.  The AppDomain detail is but one thing that can go wrong.  There is no point to it, simply add a reference to that assembly.

Comment: So first thanks for your answer. I fact, this is just an extraction of my problem (to make the problem easier to understand). In "real" this code is in c++ managed call by a native C++ application. I try to make an addin loader which load each addin in a custom domain (to add some limits between addin). Each addin can be added or remove at any moments so I cannot use static linking.

Comment: @HansPassant have tried without COM, full C# solution, without any dependency, and it still not working... Do you know what I miss ?

Comment: Why are you trying to put each addin in it's own appdomain? What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @Ben I'm trying to isolate plugin for 2 mains reason. The first is to allow each addin to have its own config file (in particular its own binding redirect). 2. To not allow addin A to break something in addin B. And each addin must be in the same process of the main application (so I cannot spawn addin in another process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an object across an `AppDomain` boundary, you need to do one of two things:

- Make the class `Serializable`, e.g. by adding the `[Serializable]` attribute.  In this case, a copy of the object is serailized and passed across the `AppDomain` boundary.  Any membes you call will be on the copy, and will not affect the original object.
- Make the class derive from [MarshalByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).  In this case, a reference to the object is marshalled across the AppDomain boundary, and any members you call will affect the object in its original AppDomain.

Comment: It's a COM interface, so it's already serializable I thinks. (COM stuff can be not serializable ???)  I cannot derive fro MarshalByRefObject because I already derive from my COM interface.

Comment: @David, `...because I already derive from my COM interface` - Why not?  You can't derive from >1 base class, but you can derive from as many interfaces as you want.  Your example class `Class` isn't deriving from anything; have you tried making this derive from `MarshalByRefObject`?

Comment: sorry my mistake, I did understand well what you say. So I have tried with the `[Serializable]` and the `MarshalByRefObject` and have still have the same serialization exception... 
```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("16c8ab2e-04b2-456-ade1-f4f69c213393")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject, MyAPI.IAddIn
    {
```

Comment: @David, your class should either inherit from MarshalByRefObject, or be Serializable (which means it will be marshalled by value), but not both.  In your case `MarshalByRefObject` is appropriate.  What is the exact exception message in this case?

Comment: the message is still the same `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'ClassLibrary2.Class1' in assembly 'ClassLibrary2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
   à System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle.Unwrap()
   à ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) dans C:\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:ligne 39`